# making environment variable permanent

Tags: shell, export

```
shell> export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
shell> history | tail -n 2
 1006  2010-01-16 00:55:47  export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
 1007  2010-01-16 00:55:49 history | tail -n 2
```

This will last as long as environment variable is set, so if I log out you will need to set it again. How do I make this permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` - one of these will be read when bash starts. `.bash_profile` is read when you login, `.bashrc` is read when you create a new interactive non-login shell (such as opening a terminal window from X)

Comment: how do you add it there?