# Adding bash history time export temporarily for output?

Tags: bash, format, history

Every once in a while I export my bash history to an external file. On occasion I would like to add `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '` so the time/date shows in the output, although it never appears in the file after I envoke the command. [**I know that you can permanently add the environment variables to your .bash_profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388054/making-environment-variable-permanent), but I just want to use it temporarily for when I use the command below. I've tried it like this:

```
# export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' | grep -v "^#" $HISTFILE > ~/path/to/output
```

with no luck showing the time/date stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' history | grep -v "^#" > ~/path/to/output
```

Note: commands that were in your history from past shells will not contain proper times unless `HISTTIMEFORMAT` was set to some value during these shells.

Answer (score 1):

it is bash that needs the environment variable:

```
env HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' bash -c 'command args'
```

Comment: Your version didn't work for me; maybe I'm not using the `command args` properly? the example jeberle posted seems to work though — thanks!